# How to pass string with \\ as string not hyperlink in python

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, styles

I am converting pandas dataframe to HTML table using python. But table data is having string which has \ in it so letters which are ahead of \ is getting converted into a hyperlink.
It's available in the table but as a hyperlink not string.

```
my string=testbackup(\\servernamenum)\folder1\scriptname.tar
```

in table
After bracket ( with both slash it's taking all string as a hyperlink.

e.g

`database_backup (**\\servername)\2020-07-21_09-39-20_backup\Database\serv_backup.tar**`

Please let me know if I need to add more information to get this clear

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is used to escape the next character and to give format instructions, such as line feed, tab, or carriage return.

If you want to store a link with actual backslashes as characters, you need a double backslash:

```
my string="testbackup(\\servernamenum)\\folder1\\scriptname.tar"
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I am using double slash only but in stackoverflow its coming as sigle slash

Comment: In that case, I don't quite understand the problem you are having. Sharing the code might help.

Answer (score 0):

try adding 'r' prefix.

```
string=r'testbackup(\servernamenum)\folder1\scriptname.tar'
```